# how do I make a backup of my entire system so I can restore it later?

Tags: 11.04, backup

I really like how my system is right now, but I want to try other versions of Ubuntu and I want to know I can go back to this setup at any moment.

I want to backup my system and all the files that are necessary for my system to work.

- I want to backup my system
- I want to be able to restore it later

How do I make this happen?